# Shooting bullets at cursor Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a top down shooter in flash using AS3 and I'm having some trouble firing a bullet from a ship moved by the WASD keys towards the cursor.  The bullets are created fine enough but they go off in random directions rather than towards where the cursor is when you press space.

This is the code for the bullet class:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
{
    var speed:Number;
    var moveX:Number;
    var moveY:Number;
    var shipX:Number;
    var shipY:Number;

    function Bullet(target:Ship)
    {
        speed = 20;
        shipX = target.x;
        shipY = target.y;

        graphics.lineStyle(7,0x000000);
        graphics.moveTo(-2,0);
        graphics.lineTo(2,0);

        graphics.lineStyle(3,0xffffff);
        graphics.moveTo(-2,0);
        graphics.lineTo(2,0);

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

    }

    function onStage (e:Event)
    {
        /*addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);

        /*var mc = 
        var angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - mc.y, mouseX - mc.x);
        var angleDegree = angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;
        mc.rotation = angleDegree;*/

        /*Ship.y += speed * Math.sin((Ship.rotation - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));
        Ship.x += speed * Math.cos((Ship.rotation - 90) * (Math.PI / 180));*/



        trace(stage.mouseY);
        var cy:Number = stage.mouseY - shipY;
        var cx:Number = stage.mouseX - shipX;

        moveX = cx / cy;
        moveY = (cy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        var Radians:Number = Math.atan2(cy,cx);
        var Degrees:Number = Radians * 180 / Math.PI;*/
    }
    function enterFrame(e:Event)
    {
        /*this.x += speed;*/

        this.x += moveX * speed;
        this.y += moveY * speed;



        if (this.x > 900)
        {
            removeEventListener("enterFrame",enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
        }
        if (this.x < 0)
        {
            removeEventListener("enterFrame",enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
        }
        if (this.y > 800)
        {
            removeEventListener("enterFrame",enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
        }
        if (this.y < 0)
        {
            removeEventListener("enterFrame",enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);
        }

        for(var i in Enemy.list)
            {
                if(this.hitTestObject(Enemy.list[i]))
                {
                    removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
                    stage.removeChild(this);
                    Enemy.list[i].kill();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

Any help getting the bullets to fire properly would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x and y velocities should be the result of cos and sin of the angle (in radians) respectively.

i.e.

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(cy, cx);
moveX = Math.cos(angle);
moveY = Math.sin(angle);
```

You then multiply both of these by the speed (which you're already doing).

Also, you don't need to calculate the degrees unless you want to rotate the graphics:

```
rotation = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: That stopped the bullets from moving, they still appear on the stage and they rotate themselves properly but they don't move from where they spawn.

Comment: @user2430308 What happens if you `trace` `moveX` and `moveY`?